# React multiple useEffect with useCallback

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm struggling a bit with the use of `useEffect` and `useCallback`. My component consists of two input field, and two select elements.

For the two input fields, I have the following `useEffect`, which triggers a setTimeout after 500ms.

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect B');
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => console.log('test'), 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [fromValue, toValue]);
```

For my two select fields, I have another simple `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect A');
  }, [fromSymbol, toSymbol]);
```

However, in both cases, I want to trigger another method, that does some calculations, so I figured, I can change my code to:

```
const calculateResult = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log('calculateResult');
    console.log(fromSymbol, toSymbol);
    console.log(fromValue, toValue);
  }, [fromSymbol, toSymbol, fromValue, toValue]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect A');
    calculateResult();
  }, [fromSymbol, toSymbol, calculateResult]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useEffect B');
    const timeout = setTimeout(() => calculateResult(), 500);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  }, [fromValue, toValue, calculateResult]);
```

But now, whenever any value is changed, both `useEffect A`, and `useEffect B` are being triggered. I assume this is because `calculateResult` is a in the `useEffect` dependency list, but if I remove it, I get the following warning: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'calculateResult'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.`

How do I solve this problem? For `fromValue` and `toValue`, I want to trigger this `calculateResult` directly, but for `fromSymbol` and `toSymbol`, I want to have a short delay.

Comment: You should not pass any dependency to `calculateResult` but if you need those values get them using `calculateResult` function parameters this way your `calculateResult` update on every dependency change which won't trigger both `useEffect A,B` so while calling `calculateResult` from `useEffect A or B` you will pass values directly as `calculateResult` function argument.

Comment: @AliHussnain But then when I use all the function arguments, it complains that the values used from `useEffect B` are not in the dependency list.

Comment: That's why I told you to pass values as function parameters in your case now you will get values whenever `calculateResult` function will be invoked. like `calculateResult(value1,value2)` and then in your `useCallback((value1,value2)=>{},[])` will be like this.

Comment: But given my example, that wouldn't work. Since my `calculateResult` would need 4 parameters, but both of my `useEffect` only have 2 dependencies.

Comment: If I pass all 4 values, then I'm back to the same problem. Where all 4 values will need to be a dependency of each `useEffect`, thus triggering both of them, which is not what I want. Can you respond with an example instead?

Comment: And passing different values in different `useEffect` wouldn't work, because ultimately, my `calculateResult` will need all 4 values to work.

Comment: Then I think don't wrap `calculateResult` in `useCallback` hook.

Comment: @AliHussnain I honestly don't know how that would even work, I would never have access to all 4 values. Could you please just post an example, since I'm really lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right `useEffect A` and `useEffect B` are both getting called because of `calculateResult`. So it was right decision to remove it from the `dependency array` and it is normal to get the warning from `react`.

```
React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'calculateResult'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.
```

Now what you can do is add

```
eslint-disable-next-line
```

in your `useEffect` to avoid the warnings. And it is normal to use it.

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect A');
  calculateResult();
  //eslint-disable-next-line
}, [fromSymbol, toSymbol]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log('useEffect B');
  const timeout = setTimeout(() => calculateResult(), 500);
  return () => clearTimeout(timeout);
  //eslint-disable-next-line
}, [fromValue, toValue]);
```

Comment: Is this safe to do? I assume those warnings are there for a reason?

Comment: `react` gives you those warnings because of `strict mode` it's kind of `double check` but it's ok to use this to avoid warnings.

Comment: It does have the desired effect. Does this also mean I won't need the `useCallback` wrapped around `calculateResult`?

Comment: yes that's right.

Comment: That is an anti-pattern and not recommended.

Comment: @AliHussnain Can you suggest a better solution?